# Is it possible to use $filters with msgraph /groups/delta?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am writing an application that is expected to sync user's detail from a group present in AAD under a given group. The plan is to use the /groups/delta endpoint.

I am trying to look for an equivalent of the following /groups query parameter for a group in /groups/delta:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=displayName+eq+'someGroup'&$expand=members`

The expectation is that the response should return newly added/removed members under 'someGroup' and optionally expand some fields ... Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There is limited support for `$filter` and `$orderby`:
>   - The only supported `$filter` expression is for tracking changes on a specific object: `$filter=id+eq+{value}`. You can `filter` multiple objects. For example, `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta/?$filter= id eq '477e9fc6-5de7-4406-bb2a-7e5c83c9ffff' or id eq '004d6a07-fe70-4b92-add5-e6e37b8affff`. There is a **limit of 50** filtered objects.

Source: [microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_delta.md)

And:

> Support for $filter operators varies across Microsoft Graph APIs. The following logical operators are generally supported:
>
> - equals (eq)
> - not equals (ne)
> - greater than (gt)
> - greater than or equals (ge)
> - less than (lt)
> - less than or equals (le)
> - and (and)
> - or (or)
> - not (not)

Source: [Use query parameters to customize responses](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#filter-parameter)

Comment: To expand a bit on this, you can use `/groups?$filter=displayName+eq+'someGroup'&$select=id` to get the Group ID and then use that to grab the delta going forward with `/groups/delta?$filter=id eq 'value'`.